# Tuple object is not callable problem.(simple cod)

Tags: python

Can someone pleases help me out this is what it says,
I am right now learning python from cs dojo when ran the code it worked but in mine its not working.... IDK why? I was trying to print "3" but idk why it didn't wok

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
print(a(2))
```

---

```
-
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-b18896fffcff> in <module>
----> 1 print(a(2))

TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: Round brackets are for calling functions, use square brackets `a[2]` to access an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Break into two lines. Index the tuple by using brackets []

```
a = (1, 2, 3) 
print(a[2])
```

Comment: when write this "a[0] = 100" the error message shows up which says this "TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-b6d7a4db9a51> in <module>
----> 1 a[0] = 100

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment" please help me out

Comment: Tuples are immutable. You cannot assign them values like an array.

Comment: i was trying to replace their values and not trying to assign them(sorry if my English is bad I am not a native speaker)

Comment: Same thing. Tuples are immutable. They cannot be modified.

Comment: Use lists rather than tuples, using square brackets: `a=[1,2,3]`. Then you can do `a[0]=100`.

Answer (score 2):

A tuple is indexed in the same way as a list, i.e. with brackets, not parenthesis:

```py
a = (1,2,3)
print(a[2])
```